# Is downstream margin the SNR margin

Tags: networking, router

My router does not have SNR Margin on the status link. It only has Downstream and Upstream margins.

Are those margins the same as SNR margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Are Downstream and Upstream margins the same as SNR margins?

Yes, they are the same.

> **Which figures do I need to look for?**
>
> Various makes of routers may name the figures slightly differently,
>   but the important figures that you are looking for should be something
>   similar to:
>
> - Connection or Sync Speed or Rate
> - Attenuation or Atten or Loop Loss
> - **SNR Margin or Noise Margin or Noise or Margin**
> - Details of any CRC/HEC/RS/FEC errors and Errored Seconds may also be helpful.

Source [How to interpret your ADSL Line Stats](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/linestats.htm)

Comment: @JackBrooks No problem.